# Imagemagick installation no good on Lion

Tags: macos, installation, imagemagick, osx-lion

I have a fresh installation of Lion. I need to install ImageMagick (IM) to use the "identify" command line tool to search for corrupt images in folders that have thousands of time lapse images.

I have installed IM from the Mac OS X Binary Release, word for word based on [these directions](https://www.imagemagick.org/script/download.php#macosx).

I have Xcode 4.2 installed from the Mac App Store.

X11 appears to be installed default with Lion. X11 about shows: XQuartz 2.6.3 (xorg-server 1.10.3).

The problem is that IM's installation appears successful but every time I use the "identify" command it returns "identify: command not found".

I have searched and searched (within stack overflow, google, etc.) and found MANY MANY articles on both subjects (IM and detecting corrupt images), but I've found nothing that helps me out.

I have also tried installing MacPorts and that didn't work either. And it freaked me out as one of it's dependencies was downloaded from Facebook.net (WHAT?!). I did a fresh install of Lion after that happened.

Thanks for your time.

Answer (score 0):

Installing ImageMagick with [Homebrew](https://brew.sh/) worked for me:

```
brew install imagemagick
```